# Suppress warnings for python-xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, suppress-warnings, python-xarray

I'm running the following code

```
positive_values = values.where(values > 0)
```

In this example `values` may contain `nan` elements. I believe that for this reason, I'm getting the following runtime warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal if not reflexive
```

Does `xarray` have methods of surpressing these warnings?

Comment: something like `positive_values = values.where(values.notnull & values > 0)`?

Comment: I like the suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html) module provides the functionality you are looking for.

To suppress all warnings do (see [John Coleman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126444/1322401) for why this is not good practice):

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore") 
# warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning) # for RuntimeWarning only
```

To make the suppression temporary do it inside the `warnings.catch_warnings()` context manager:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    positive_values = values.where(values > 0)
```

The context manager saves the original warning settings prior to entering the context and then sets them back when exiting the context.

Comment: Thank you for such a speedy response. 

I'm a fan of brevity/readability. This adds a lot of noise to code in terms of readability. Are there ways to use the warning library to globally suppress certain warnings( IE: Runtime Warning)? Or is this the best python has at the moment?

Comment: At the top of your main module do `import warnings;warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)`.  This will supress all RuntimeWarnings.  As @JohnColeman points out, this is not a good practice.  These warnings exist for a reason.  I would especially warn against a global supression of warnings because you don't know what warnings you will end up missing.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb, warnings should be heeded rather than suppressed. Either you know what causes the warning or you don't. If you know what causes the warning, there is usually a simple workaround. If you don't know what causes the warning, there is likely a bug. In this case, you can use the short-circuiting nature of `&` as follows:

```
positive_values = values.where(values.notnull() & values > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. I've opened a question about why the warning is thrown in the first place If you're interested. You can find it at
:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130138/why-is-invalid-value-encountered-in-greater-warning-thrown-in-python-xarray-fo