# Why is 'invalid value encountered in greater' warning thrown in python xarray for nan? Shouldn't the nan commute without any issues?

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

The following is philosophical question aimed at figuring out why xarrays is the way that it is.

---

I'm having trouble figuring out the Xarrays way to do the following.

```
positive_values = values.where(values > 0)
```

It follows x-arrays syntax, and computes what I want it to do using xarrays, but throws this Runtime Warning.

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater if not reflexive
```

My question is, **how am I abusing Xarrays**?

I'd like to make the case that `nans` are excellent in the sense that they commute across across operations. (Making it easy to spot or deal with  missing data values)

IE.

```
value = np.nan + 1  
final_value = value/2  
#final_value evaluates to 'nan'
```

This make their representation in X-arrays very useful. `xarrays` may have missing data, but that shouldn't stop an operation across thousands of points.

Why doesn't `>` commute the `nan` without any issue? Should I be doing this some other way and ignore the error if this is the behavior that I want?

Comment: No answer, just a comment for what it's worth: `nan` ≠ `nan` (i.e. `nan` == `nan` is `False`), so a `nan` violates the reflexive property of equality.  Perhaps that is what the error message is referring to.

Comment: Can you supply a reproducible example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was not an intentional design choice and should be fixed.

NumPy issues warnings when doing comparisons with NaN, because the result may be surprising, at least if you are not familiar with how comparisons with NaN work:

```
In [6]: np.array([1, -1, np.nan]) > 0
/Users/shoyer/conda/envs/xarray-dev/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  #!/Users/shoyer/conda/envs/xarray-dev/bin/python
Out[6]: array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Arguably, it would be more intuitive if the result was something like `[True, False, NA]`, but NumPy doesn't have integrated missing value support.

Until recently (in [pandas 0.19](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#fine-grained-numpy-errstate)), pandas silenced NumPy warnings of this type for all operations -- whether or not the operation was done with using pandas. Because xarray imports pandas, this meant these errors were silenced for xarray operations, too. Now, we'll need to add our own code to silence these warningss.

**Update:** This should be resolved as of xarray v0.10. If you are still encountering it, please file a bug at http://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues